# How to receive input for connect-n in C

Tags: c, pointers

In the game of connect-N, you only need the players to input a column. However, I'm a little stuck on how to make the player's move at the lowest open spot on the board. My program for getting the player's move is this:

```
void getMove(char **board, const int numRows, const int numCols, const 
char blankSpace, int *row, int *col) {
  int numArgsRead;
  const int numArgsNeeded = 1;

  do {
    printf("Enter a column between 0 and %d to play in: ", numCols - 1);
    numArgsRead = scanf("%d", col);

    for (int i = numRows - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      if (board[i][*col] != blankSpace) {
        continue;
      }
      else {
        *row = i;
      }
    }
  } while(!isMoveValid(numArgsRead, numArgsNeeded, board, numRows, numCols, *row, 
*col, blankSpace));
}
```

Note: isMoveValid basically takes all those parameters and determines if the arguments are integers, if the (row,col) is on the board, and if the spot is blank.

I call getMove from main, and I was hoping that this function would "return" the row and columns values to the variables rowPlayed and colPlayed, which I defined in main. I know col is assigned its correct value based upon the user input, but I'm not sure why the for loop doesn't assign the corresponding row index to *row. Any suggestions?

Edit: this is my main.c

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  const char blankSpace = '*';
  const int numRows = atoi(argv[1]);
  const int numCols = atoi(argv[2]);
  const int numToWin = atoi(argv[3]);
  const char pieces[] = "XO";
  int rowPlayed, colPlayed;
  int playerTurn = 1; // 0 is player 1, 1 is player 2

  correctNumOfArgs(argc, numRows, numCols, numToWin);

  char** board = createBoard(numRows, numCols, blankSpace);

  do {
    playerTurn = changeTurn(playerTurn);

    displayBoard(board, numRows, numCols);

    getMove(board, numRows, numCols, blankSpace, &rowPlayed, &colPlayed);

    makeMove(board, rowPlayed, colPlayed, pieces[playerTurn]);

  } while(!isGameOver(board, numRows, numCols, blankSpace, numToWin, pieces[playerTurn]));

  declareOutcome(playerTurn, board, numRows, numCols, blankSpace, numToWin, pieces[playerTurn]);

  cleanUp(&board, numRows, numCols);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your main code as well?  It helps if we can build and run your code :)

Comment: @Michi scanf reads the user input into the pointer variable col, and is also assigned to the variable numArgsRead. Since it read one value, it will assign numArgsRead a value of 1, which is equal to numArgsNeeded.

Comment: @roelofs I'm not sure my main code will be that helpful to you, as it's just a bunch of function calls. But I'll post it anyways

Comment: Replace `atoi` with `strtol` and validate the conversion. `atoi` provides absolutely no way to insure the user didn't enter `./program foo bar baz`.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)." Without a MCVE, we cannot be sure problems are not generated in `createBoard`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can see, the correct row index is assigned just fine in `*row = i;` but you have to break the loop after assigning, otherwise the first assignment will be overridden.

Full loop suggestion:

```
for (int i = numRows - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    if (board[i][*col] == blankSpace)
    {
        *row = i;
        break;
    }
}
```